# iOS: How to align top and bottom in a scroll view SwiftUi

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have an app that contains a custom made side menu. I am struggling to make the items in items array start from the top and make the itemsBottom array stick to the bottom of the scroll view.

```
import SwiftUI

struct MenuItemTest: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    let text: String
}


struct TestView: View {
    
    let items: [MenuItemTest] = [
        MenuItemTest(text: "test1"),
        MenuItemTest(text: "test2"),
        MenuItemTest(text: "test3"),
        MenuItemTest(text: "test4"),
        MenuItemTest(text: "test5"),
        MenuItemTest(text: "test6"),
        MenuItemTest(text: "test7"),
        MenuItemTest(text: "test8"),
        MenuItemTest(text: "test9")
    ]
    
    let itemsBottom : [MenuItemTest] = [
        MenuItemTest(text: "test10"),
        MenuItemTest(text: "test11"),
        MenuItemTest(text: "test12"),
        MenuItemTest(text: "test13")
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            Color(UIColor(red: 33/255.0, green: 33/255.0, blue: 33/255.0, alpha: 1))
            
            ScrollView {
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
                    
                    ForEach(items) { item in
                        HStack {
                            Text(item.text)
                                .bold()
                                .font(.system(size: 20))
                                .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                            Spacer()
                        }
                        .padding(10)
                        
                        Divider()
                    }
                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                }
                .padding(.top, 30)
                
                
                VStack() {
                    ForEach(itemsBottom) { item in
                        HStack {
                            Text(item.text)
                                .bold()
                                .font(.system(size: 13))
                                .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                            Spacer()
                        }
                        .padding(10)
                        
                        Divider()
                    }
                    Spacer()
                }
                
            }
        }
        
    }
}

struct TestView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestView()
    }
}
```

As seen in the picture the 2 sections are one after another however I want the bottom array too append to the bottom, I am wondering if anyone can advise please.

The code I added is slight difference to picture but basically the same

Thanks

[image: Picture]

[image: Picture from android version]

First picture show show it is now on the iOS app, and the second one with the red lines show the current android version and how I want it

Comment: It's scroll view so scroll view size is not fixed. You can adjust both. what happens if the size is small and the menu row is more??? how you can manage it?

Comment: ScrollView takes all of the available space, by default. It is perfectly aligned.

Comment: Also, in android not possible. possible in android don't use a scroll or use scroll only for the first section and the second section is out of the scroll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the scrollView and calculate the dynamic height of Htstack wrt screen height , something like this:

Result:
[image]

```
   struct ContentView: View {
    
    let items: [MenuItemTest] = [
        MenuItemTest(text: "test1"),
        MenuItemTest(text: "test2"),
        MenuItemTest(text: "test3"),
        MenuItemTest(text: "test4"),
        MenuItemTest(text: "test5"),
        MenuItemTest(text: "test6"),
        MenuItemTest(text: "test7"),
        MenuItemTest(text: "test8"),
        MenuItemTest(text: "test9")
    ]
    
    let itemsBottom : [MenuItemTest] = [
        MenuItemTest(text: "test10"),
        MenuItemTest(text: "test11"),
        MenuItemTest(text: "test12"),
        MenuItemTest(text: "test13")
    ]
    
    let spacerHeight: CGFloat = 50
    let topPadding: CGFloat = 30
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            Color(UIColor(red: 33/255.0, green: 33/255.0, blue: 33/255.0, alpha: 1))
            ScrollView {
                VStack {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
                        
                        ForEach(items) { item in
                            HStack {
                                Text(item.text)
                                    .bold()
                                    .font(.system(size: 20))
                                    .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                                Spacer()
                            }.frame(height: (UIScreen.main.bounds.height - (spacerHeight + topPadding))/CGFloat((items.count + itemsBottom.count)))
                        }
                    }.padding(.top, topPadding)
                    Spacer(minLength: spacerHeight)
                    VStack() {
                        ForEach(itemsBottom) { item in
                            HStack {
                                Text(item.text)
                                    .bold()
                                    .font(.system(size: 13))
                                    .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                                Spacer()
                            }.frame(height: (UIScreen.main.bounds.height - (spacerHeight + topPadding))/CGFloat((items.count + itemsBottom.count)))
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}
```

Comment: This works great thank you, however when the device is rotated then the side menu becomes really compaqt and would be better with some scroll. So how would this issue be solveable? 
Thanks for helping BTW.

Comment: Wrap it in scrollView, I've updated the answer check it.